# SQL Server SELECT Money as blank space instead of 0.00

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am having trouble getting my values to come back as blank instead of 0.00 in a table variable.

Table Setup/Declaration.

```
        DECLARE @PolicyCoverages TABLE (
        CoverageType varchar(100),
        ScheduleLimit money,
        BlanketLimit money,
        Deductible money,
        Premium money
    )

    INSERT INTO @PolicyCoverages (CoverageType, ScheduleLimit, BlanketLimit, Deductible, Premium)    
    SELECT  'Words for a description',
            '10000.00', 
            '0.00', 
            '2500.00', 
            '142.50'
```

Once all the data is in place (there are many selects that pull in data) I want to pull specific information as shown below.

```
SELECT CoverageType,
       CASE WHEN ScheduleLimit < 0 THEN '' ELSE ScheduleLimit END AS ScheduleLimit,
       CASE BlanketLimit WHEN '0.00' THEN '' ELSE BlanketLimit END AS BlanketLimit,
       Deductible, 
       Premium 
    FROM @PolicyCoverages
    WHERE (ScheduleLimit > '0.00') OR (BlanketLimit > '0.00')
```

I do NOT want to display 0.00 I instead want a blank space ''.  I've tried converts, I tried cast, and the two shown WHEN attempts.

```
WHEN CAST(ScheduleLimit as varchar(10)) < 0 THEN ''
WHEN Schedulelilmit < 0 THEN CONVERT(varchar(10), '')
```

No matter which way I attempt this it comes over as 0.00

Comment: `ScheduleLimit` is a number, why are you comparing it to strings?: `WHERE (ScheduleLimit > '0.00')`....and you also compare it to a number when you explicitely convert it to a string: `WHEN CAST(ScheduleLimit as varchar(10)) < 0`.

Comment: Hint: `IIF` , `CASE`

Comment: Of course it is not going to be an empty string. Your datatype is money and an empty string will implicitly convert to 0.00. Maybe you should use NULL instead empty string. Or even better, let the front end handle zero suppression.

Comment: Why pass numbes as strings? Where did these strings come from? Is the query generated by string concatenation perhaps? Quoting isn't going to prevent SQL injections or conversion errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want '' that is character, you need to convert your money to varchar like this:

```
SELECT CoverageType,
       CASE WHEN ScheduleLimit < 0 THEN '' ELSE cast(ScheduleLimit as varchar(30)) END AS ScheduleLimit,
       CASE BlanketLimit WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE cast(BlanketLimit as varchar(30)) END AS BlanketLimit,
       Deductible, 
       Premium 
    FROM @PolicyCoverages
    WHERE (ScheduleLimit > '0.00') OR (BlanketLimit > '0.00')
```

If you don't want your `money` become `varchar`, you should use `NULL` instead of ''.

You cannot display `money` and `char` in the same column, so you have no other choices: or you convert all the column to `varchar`, or you preserve `money` but use `NULL` instead of ''.

Comment: NULL indeed corrects it!  Good detail in your answer too!

Answer (score 0):

Use the SPACE(n) function to get the spacebars. 'n' is an integer

Comment: This doesn't work. The OP has the money datatype so a space will still be implicitly converted to 0.00

Answer (score 0):

[Sean Lange](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3813116/sean-lange) got it! Displaying the NULL did correct my issue.  The front end (which I don't have control of) displays NULL values as blanks already so setting it to NULL corrects all.

```
SELECT CoverageType,
       CASE ScheduleLimit WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE ScheduleLimit END AS ScheduleLimit,
       CASE BlanketLimit WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE BlanketLimit END AS BlanketLimit,
       Deductible, 
       Premium 
    FROM @PolicyCoverages
    WHERE (ScheduleLimit > 0) OR (BlanketLimit > 0)
```